# Highlight current touched item as selected item

Tags: android, select, setbackground

I have a android file explorer application and  I need to highlight the selected item. I could select touched items using v.setBackgroundColor() method inside onListItemClick(). But when I touch another file/folder still previous one highlighted. I need only current touched item display as selected. How to do this?

Comment: Post your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not perfect but works good

loop through all items of list and try something like this

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            for (int i = 0; i < arg0.getCount(); i++) {

                View view = arg0.getChildAt(i);
                if (i == arg2) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                } else {

                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: I have ListView instead AdapterView as the parameter. I tried this, but still it is not work. Only last item is highlight when touched. Also it is keep remaining highlight when touch another one.

Comment: change arg1 to view in else part.